# Questions about Wordpress 3.0 RC

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, upgrade, themes

I'm looking to upgrade my blog from Wordpress 2.5 to 3.0 RC, but I'm not sure if:

1. It is stable?
2. It will support existing v2.5 plugins?
3. It will support my custom themes? Or do I have to design them from scratch for 3.0?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is stable?

Yes, it is more stable now.

> It will support existing v2.5 plugins?

There may be some plugins supported other may not depending on whether plugins have been updated by plugin authors.

> It will support my custom themes? Or
>   do I have to design them from scratch
>   for 3.0?

Yes, you can use your custom themes as well as new ones...

Comment: Just to clarify: themes are like the plugins in that they could be using obsolete function calls and thus will break. 

Best thing to do, if you can, would be to get some kind of development environment set up to test your site with the new version.

There are a couple of options: You could install WP 3.0 in a subfolder on your server, duplicate your database, and then duplicate your themes and plugins in to this install to do a test run. Another option is to install a LAMP stack on a computer that you own (MAMP/XAMP can help with this).

2.5 to 3.0 is a big jump and should be taken carefully.

Comment: @Gipetto: That's useful comment adding to the answer. In fact i have written an article on how to check new themes here: http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/04/11/testing-wordpress-themes-easily/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "existing 2.9 plugins"?  Version 2.5 is years-old at this point. (March 29, 2008, in fact.  From: http://wordpress.org/about/roadmap/)

As Gipetto stated, there have been a lot (alot! *grin*) of WordPress API changes, as well as database schema changes since 2.5. If you're attempting a direct migration from 2.5 to 3.0RC1, there's a high likelihood that something will break.

However, the upsides to staying in-sync with the latest WP release far outweigh the downsides in my opinion.